# Method modifier ordering in Java

Tags: java, methods, syntax, modifier

From what I understand this is how a typical method is defined:

```
modifier returnValueType methodName(list of parameters) {
    // Method body;
}
```

However if you have several modifiers, (e.g. `public`, `static`, `<GenericType>`) Is there a particular order they should be in?

This is a model answer to one of my past exams questions:

```
<S> public void emptyList(CyclicQueue<S> queue) {
    while(!queue.isEmpty()) { queue.pop(); }
}
```

As you can see the generic modifier `<S>` comes before `public` but I have seen this reversed in some places:

```
public <S> void emptyList(CyclicQueue<S> queue) {
    while(!queue.isEmpty()) { queue.pop(); }
}
```

Which is the correct, or the more conventional way of ordering these modifiers?

Answer (score 3):

This [website](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_modifier.html) gives you a rough guide of the ordering of the modifiers.

Generics should also be declared after public methods.

```
public <S> void emptyList(CyclicQueue<S> queue) {
   while(!queue.isEmpty()) { queue.pop(); }
}
```

NOT

```
<S> public void emptyList(CyclicQueue<S> queue) {
    while(!queue.isEmpty()) { queue.pop(); }
}
```

The model answer will not work as your modifier public,protected,default of private takes precedence over the generic type.

Comment: Gives you *an* ordering of the modifiers. It isn't compulsory. The link is incorrect to claim that there is a 'correct order'.

Comment: Agreed.The ordering is not compulsory but it is convention and kinda easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

Generic type is not modifier and in generic method should be placed before return type like

```
public <S> void emptyList(CyclicQueue<S> queue) {
//         ^^^^ return type
    while(!queue.isEmpty()) { queue.pop(); }
}
```

Model answer from your question will not compile.

Answer (score 1):

I dont believe its legal to put  before the access keyword. In other words,

```
public <S> void emptyList(CyclicQueue<S> queue) {
    while(!queue.isEmpty()) { queue.pop(); }
}
```

is correct. The main funciton in Java actually answers most of your question -

```
public static void main(String[] args){
```

Here you can see the proper ordering: access level, static, return type. Adding a generic type is just a replacement for the return type.